# border with circle dots and border radius

Tags: html, css

want to create div with border of 100% radius and also which would have circle dots not squere...

and everything what I found to was in the code snipped, but in this case don't have any radius.. :/

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #dfbc82;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: url('https://d3uepj124s5rcx.cloudfront.net/items/0V28170w0f0k3t3S2p0g/dots.svg');
  border-image-slice: 33%;
  border-image-repeat: round;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
```

is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: This http://codepen.io/luclemo/pen/xbMdEx will work.

Comment: I was trying by this example... but I can't get border-radius working..

Comment: Hey. There are lots of wrong code you have used. Check this out [Simple Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/grinex/8yy3pn36/) . Make this as your guide, hope it helps.